# How to find element id by specific text and click on it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a bot to book a gym/gym classes.

I have managed to get throught login page etc.. but can't figure out how to search for text in element and click on it.

HTML page source:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ClassStatus$ctrl0$btnBook" value="Book" id="ctl00_MainContent_ClassStatus_ctrl0_btnBook" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-qai-id="button-ActivityID=B7GYMSB16300321 ResourceID=30212837 Duration=60 Status=Available Date=23/06/2021 16:30:00" />
```

So when I ask my bot to click on it via element id - it works just fine

```
  driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_ClassStatus_ctrl0_btnBook').click()
```

The only problem is this element id is not set in stone, it does change for specific time/day/etc...

In html source I can see:

```
data-qai-id="button-ActivityID=B7GYMSB16300321 ResourceID=30212837 Duration=60 Status=Available Date=23/06/2021 16:30:00"
```

Is there any way to look for part of that test in data-qai-id = Date=23/06/2021 16:30:00 and then click on element_id containing it??

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

No you should use the date format for this purpose :

```
 Date=23/06/2021 16:30:00
```

cause it going to be different evert time and your code will never work. try the below xpath

```
//input[contains(@name, 'MainContent_ClassStatus_')]
```

or

```
//input[contains(@id, 'MainContent_ClassStatus_') and @value='Book' and contains(@name, '$MainContent$ClassStatus$ctr')]
```

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enought, but on the website I can see many elements with different ID's and TEXT in data-qai-id.


ID like ctl03_MainContent_ClassStatus_ctrl0_btnBook does change every day so I cannot use this to target element as I do not know what its going to be for the booking I want to make.

However as I mentioned earlier in the data-qai-id there is some text containing date and time I want to use for the booking so by looking for element id with that specific text I can book what I want.

Comment: Can you share URL or full page source ?

Comment: thanks so much, you gave me idea - I just need to use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@data-qai-id,'24/06/2021')]").click()

Answer (score -1):

See if this works:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@value='Book']").click()
```